# python on Mac OS X Lion “ImportError: cannot import name urandom”

Tags: python, macos

Since I last updated python (nonw 2.7.3) using macport, I got the following issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 4, in File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 46, 
in import email.utils File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/email/utils.py", line 27, 
in import random File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 47, 
in from os import urandom as _urandom 
ImportError: cannot import name urandom
```

I am running on:

- OS X version 10.7.5
- python version 2.7.3
- $PATH: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Can you please help me out ? Thanks

Comment: I had similar issue with vim and python-mode, this helped for me https://github.com/klen/python-mode/issues/87 **but** it's not the same issue - but they give advice on chasing down the issue. No matter how tangental to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Xcode command line tools.